# PHP reference variable, Why is $a = 21?

Tags: php, reference

Can someone explain to me in a simple language why $a = 21 in the final output?

```
$a = '1';    
echo $a . "<br>"; // result 1

$b = &$a;
echo $b . "<br>"; // result 1

$b = "2$b";
echo $b . "<br>"; // result 21

echo $a . "<br>"; // result 21 WHY?

echo $a . ", " . $b; // result 21, 21
```

Thank you. I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: Well, you assign "21" to `$b` which is a reference to `$a`. That is what references are for...

Comment: Read on [string parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) and [assigning by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference).

Comment: it's an excercise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because when you do

```
$b = "2$b";
```

it means "Set the value of $b to the string "2" followed by whatever the current value of $b is.

Earlier you  put

```
$b = &$a;
```

This means "create a new reference for $a and call it $b", or in other words make $b point at the same thing in memory that $a is pointing at.

When you update the value of $b you're really updating the value that's stored in the memory block that both $a and $b point at, so once you've set $b to a particular value $a will be the same value because they both reference the same thing.

Comment: Maybe the confusion is why, when re-setting the value of `$b`, it's still pointing to the same memory address instead of pointing to the new string `2$b`? One could assume that `$b` is a pointer to `$a` and when re-assigning its value, it points to another memory address (pretty much what C does).

Comment: Ahhh,, @GordonM, thank you. Gotcha.. I think I get it.

Comment: This explained it to me "when you update the value of $b you're really updating the value that's stored in the memory block that both $a and $b point at"